# How do I deploy a release from DevOps via the API

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I have been able to do everything except deploy the release through the API. I have search all documentation and come up empty. Am I missing something?

Comment: as per Levi's answer. You POST to create a new release and then you PATCH that release to deploy your required environment. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update-release-environment?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Answer (score 3):

You can use [create release rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to deploy a new release.

`POST https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.1`

See below example in powershell script:

See steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) to get Personal access token(PAT).

```
$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.1"

$PAT= "Personal access token"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))

$body= '{
    "definitionId": 3
    }'

$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body
```

If you want to redeploy a existing stage. You can use [update release environment rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update%20release%20environment?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

`PATCH https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}?api-version=5.1-preview.6`

See below script example:

```
$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}?api-version=5.1-preview.6"
    
$PAT= "Personal access token"
    
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))
#set status to inProgress to redeploy the stage
$body= '{
         "status": "inProgress"
        }'
    
$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method patch -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body
```

Comment: With the update API you are also able to start a deployment in any environment on a release: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update-release-environment?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#start-deployment-on-an-environment

Answer (score 0):

As of now there are two endpoints to trigger Pipelines and Classic Releases.

Check this out for Release operations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1